# How to generate empty get & set statements using CODEDOM in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

currently the code which i have is generating the properties like

```
private int integerProperty  
         { 
            get  
            { 
                return integerField; 
            }
            set  
            { 
                integerField = value; 
            } 
        }
```

I wanted the properties to be simple like...

```
private int integerProperty  
         { 
            get;              
            set; 
         }
```

The code i have with me is

```
 CodeMemberProperty property1 = new CodeMemberProperty();
        property1.GetStatements.Add(new CodeMethodReturnStatement(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), "integerField")));
        property1.SetStatements.Add(new CodeAssignStatement(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), "integerField"),new CodePropertySetValueReferenceExpression()));
        type1.Members.Add(property1);
```

Anyone please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As Botz3000 mentioned, it's officially not possible. However, with the following hack you can implement it:

```
var field = new CodeMemberField
  {
      Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final,
      Name = "MyProperty",
      Type = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(MyType)),
  };

  field.Name += " { get; set; }";
```

By appending `{ get; set; }` to the field name, it will generate a property in the actual source code.

Comment: Thanks Wouter de Kort :) You saved my time.

Comment: Hi Wouter, the code works perfectly .. but it is adding a semicolon (;) at the end..     public class Sample {
        
        public int ID{ get; set; };
        
        public string Name{ get; set; };
        
        public string Domain{ get; set; };
        
       }  Please note that at the end of the property u can find a semicolon.

Comment: A work around for this is to type: field.Name += " { get; set; }//" The '//' causing the extra semicolon to be commented out.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but is worth noting that the answer by "@Serguei Fedorov" is no longer applies (it's valid only for c# 1.0 to c# 2.0)

The solution of replacing "};" with "}"  should be avoid, because "};" is used for the syntax of Object and Collection Initializers starting from  C# 3.0.

Review  [Object and Collection Initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx).

Example:

```
 var pet = new { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };  //it's ended by "};"
```

**Alternative solution**

You can use [the new .NET Compiler Platform ("Roslyn")](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn)  which support C# 1.0 to c#6.0.

The [samples](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Samples/CSharp/ConvertToAutoProperty)  include  ConvertToAutoProperty - A code refactoring to change a simple property with a trivial getter and setter into an auto property.

If you interested by CodeDom, there's a new [CodeDOM Providers for .NET Compiler Platform (“Roslyn”)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform/)  that can be installed from nuget

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. Automatic properties are a language specific feature, so you won't find any way to generate those.